# Não consigo Publicar aplicativo na Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Já está Tudo correto, porem o botão pra iniciar lançamento não fica ativo!
segue prints! ja tentei enviar diversas versões, mudar texto, tudo, mais nada funciona!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e quanto a essa aba "Produtos no app"? Ela esta com uma exclamação.... Talvez tenha algo necessário pra se configurar ali

Comment: adicione as notas da versao

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza!? é sua primeira publicação? se for, lá em cima onde vc tampou o print tem as informações que estão faltando para vc pode publicar.

Geralmente é a classificação de conteúdo(que só pode ser feita dps que vc upar o app), e a disponibilidade e preços do app. Fique atendo para marcar as opções que seu app está dentro das diretrizes, e se tem conteúdo para crianças.

Verifique aba por aba e veja se tem algum campo obrigatório que ficou pra trás.